# C# - using dataset in another form without passing dataset

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I'm making game using c# and mysql.
The game starts with 'host' and 'client' button and if user clicks 'host' button, it stores the user's ip address to mysql and dataset so that client can choose the host using ip address.
The order of form is like this:

CASE 1 : 'host' button clicked,

Form1 -> Form2 -> Form4 -> Form5 -> Form6

```
    (Form2 : get host ip and store it to mysql, dataset)
```

CASE 2 : 'client' button clicked,
Form1 -> Form3 -> Form4 -> Form5 -> Form6

```
    (Form3 : create labels at runtime depending on # of host's ip address )
```

I could save data to database successfully, but I couldn't use the dataset in Form3 and couldn't come up with good idea as well.
I would really appreciate it if you can help me out!

Here is a bit of code:

Form1.cs:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1();
    DataTable dt_host = new DataTable();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dt_host.Columns.Add("ip");
    }

    private void host_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        Form2 form2 = new Form2(ds);
        form2.ShowDialog();
        this.Close();
    }

    private void client_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        Form3 form3 = new Form3(ds);
        form3.ShowDialog();
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Form2.cs:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public static String strConn;
    DataSet1 ds;
    DataTable dt_host;

    public Form2(DataSet1 set) {
        ds = set;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void SelectData() {
        string sql = "select ip from host";
        MySqlDataAdapter adpt = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
        adpt.Fill(ds, "host");
    }
}
```

Form3: //ERROR!!!!!!!! :

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Cannot find Tables[0]

```
public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    DataSet1 ds;
    DataTable dt;

    public Form3(DataSet1 dataset) {
        ds = dataset;
        InitializeComponent();

        count = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
        MessageBox.Show(count.ToString());

    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `DataSet` in this context? I would use a custom object.

Comment: Why don't you tell us the error you get? And why do you close form1?

Comment: @FrancescoB. Then how do you use the DataSet (which is created on Form2) on Form3?

Comment: @TaW The error says 'Cannot find Tables[0]' so that means I'm not using the DataSet (which is created on Form2) on Form3. And I closed the Form1 because the function of Form1 is over.

Comment: In the code you show there is only one DS and it is created in Form1. You pass a reference to it when opening Forms2&3. It looks correct. I wonder why the error doesn't say 'index out of bounds' if there is no table in the ds.. I suggest you __copy the full error message into the question__. - When is case 2 happening: After clicking case one or after re-starting  the program?

Comment: You do realize that a DS/DT are C# and not DBMS objects and that they need to be connected and filled from the DBMS on each run..?

Comment: @TaW I added the full error message on the post and the error happens right after I click 'client' button on Form 1. Then how do I show the data of database without connection to DBMS?

Comment: @Taw Because  when Form3 is opened, client needs to be able to choose host ip address